# Slider is stuck on the first slide

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have a slider in the front page: https://unicarmodel.com/
The slider is stuck on the first slide.
I can see there is a problem with jquery on the console, but how to fix it?
It worked before...
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Just include following code

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js'>
```

Comment: You need to add it before the slider script, even if it is in the footer.

Comment: how can do it in wordpress?

Comment: In your functions.php, using wp_register_script() and wp_enqueue_script()

Comment: Try this https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js